# getting sum of column and not delete some records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

here are some data from the tables

slm

| id | grade_level | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Grade 1 | 1st Grading Period |
| 2 | Grade 2 | 2nd Grading Period |

slm_activities

| id | slmid | activity | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 77 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 72 | 6 |

period

| id | period |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st Grading Period |
| 2 | 2nd Grading Period |
| 3 | 3rd Grading Period |
| 4 | 4th Grading Period |

activities

| id | activity |
| --- | --- |
| 72 | lesson |
| 75 | page |
| 77 | quiz |

i need to get this kind of output for mysql it will display all kinds of activities and for all periods then sum their count value, activitycount will display 0 if it doesn't encounter other activities for that period

| activitycount | activity | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | quiz | 1st Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 4th Grading Period |
| 0 | lesson | 1st Grading Period |
| 6 | lesson | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | lesson | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 1st Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 4th Grading Period |

this is my current mysql query

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS activitycount, activities.activity, periods.period
FROM slm_activities 
LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id = slm_activities.activity 
LEFT JOIN slm ON slm_activities.slmid = slm.id 
LEFT JOIN periods ON periods.period = slm.period
GROUP BY activities.activity, periods.period
```

Comment: You did not specify in your question what's wrong whith your current query, but I guess you need the period table in the leftmost position in the from clause, otherwise you will not see all the periods in the output. And may have to right join the activities table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to show all periods for each activities, you need to use `CROSS JOIN` for this. Also the table `slm` should store the `id` of `periods` table instead of `period` field.

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(count, 0)) AS activitycount, activities.activity, periods.period
FROM activities
CROSS JOIN periods
LEFT JOIN slm ON periods.period = slm.period
LEFT JOIN slm_activities ON activities.id = slm_activities.activity
 AND slm.id = slm_activities.slmid
GROUP BY activities.activity, periods.period
ORDER BY activities.activity, periods.period;
```

Result

| activitycount | activity | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | lesson | 1st Grading Period |
| 6 | lesson | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | lesson | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | lesson | 4th Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 1st Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | page | 4th Grading Period |
| 5 | quiz | 1st Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 2nd Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 3rd Grading Period |
| 0 | quiz | 4th Grading Period |

##### See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8448e1cb1ffb8918a5d7dd1e65544675).

Comment: Thanks for this ! :) didnt know how cross joins work yet but thankyou for helping me understand it :)